# Simple discord.py mp3 bot not playing music

Tags: python, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py, pynacl

Discord bot dosent play anykind of music, neither mine nor other bots codes work he just dosent play music. idk maybe i am just stupid BUT IT DOSENT WORK WHY

```
import discord
import time
import os
from discord.ext import commands

BOT_TOKEN = "" # put token here

intentss = discord.Intents.default()
intentss.message_content = True
intentss.voice_states = True

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=";;", intents = intentss)

OPUS_LIBS = ['libopus-0.x86.dll', 'libopus-0.x64.dll', 'libopus-0.dll', 'libopus.so.0', 'libopus.0.dylib']

@bot.command()
async def join(ctx):
    channelVC = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channelVC.connect()

@bot.command()
async def leave(ctx):
    await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

@bot.command()
async def play(ctx):
    voice = ctx.guild.voice_client
    mloc = 'C:/Users/Lukas/Desktop/Bot Bethoven/Youtube/test.mp3'
    voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable = "C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source = mloc))


bot.run(BOT_TOKEN)
```

it just give error codes:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ClientException: Not connected to voice.
INFO     discord.player ffmpeg process 22896 has not terminated. Waiting to terminate...
INFO     discord.player ffmpeg process 22896 should have terminated with a return code of 1.
```

intresting thing when i put join and play in the same command it dosent show not connected to voice error, actually it dosent show anything and neither plays mp3 file

i tryed reinstalling: PyNaCl, FFmpeg, Visual Code, updating python.
nothing helps. this problem started after i did 1 month break from coding bot, before that it worked fine.

i'm thinking problem is something with my pc, maybe path or something dosent work(because it worked month ago and i didnt do anything to code), i tryed checking but everything seems normal,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me it was something with diffrent versions of python's i used, they did something to eatch other soo it just broke

fix for me was to DELETE everything asociated with Python (that includes modules) and reinstall it.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I think that after the line:

```
voice.play(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(executable = "C:/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe", source = mloc))
```

Python finish the process, so cant execute properly the line, try to put this after

```
while voice.is_playing():
     await asyncio.sleep(1)
voice.disconnect()
```

Secondly, as I know with "ctx.guild.voice_client" which is a VoiceProtocol, you can´t use the methods of play(),pause() etc..., but firstly try with the lines that I said you, you should have a Exception of Attribute dosen´t exist.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
channelVC = ctx.author.voice.channel
```

See with debug what is returning, should return a VocalGuildChannel object.
But it dosen´t to be that case, so you have to secure what happens with "ctx.author.voice" because it is returning maybe None, secure that your profile is in a voice channel to be functional.

Comment: Sorry can't tell you if you are right or wrong here, because all i did was just reinstall all python releated stuff, didn't toutch the code, and it just started to work perfectly. Cant even replicate the problem